# Spectators or bystanders at a public event are "in the ___"?

Tags: word-choice

I do not know if it is correct or wrong to use in this sentence. I want to refer to large amount of people as viewers.

> If you were living in the middle ages, I am sure you would be the one "in the public" who threw stones at the hanging or burned bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is *crowd*.  Your sentence should read:

> If you **had lived** in the middle ages, I am sure you **would have been** the one in the **crowd** who threw stones **at** the hanging or burned bodies.

(Please note: I made a few additional changes just so the tense was consistent. I'm not sure exactly which tense you wanted to express; if this isn't the right one, let me know and I'll edit to correct.)

Merriam-Webster [defines a *crowd* as](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crowd):

> : a large number of persons especially when collected together : throng

Comment: An even stronger word would be *mob*, as in *lynch mob*.

Comment: @Wendikidd Thank you, living in the past but continuously in an indefinite period of time. I like throng! :)

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, good thought!  A mob is basically an angry or overexcited crowd, after all, which fits perfectly in the sentence. :) (Readers should note that it has a negative connotation in case they wish to use it in other circumstances, however.)

Comment: @user37324 Ah, I see, like time travel then?  In that case you ought to say "If you were living in the middle ages, I am sure you would be the one in the crowd throwing stones...". :)  And yes, throng is a good word!  Glad to have helped :)

Comment: And mob too! :)

Comment: Is it wrong to use "were lived" ? I prefer to not use of were living but if "were lived" is incorrect I choose " had lived " instead.

Comment: @user37324 Yes, were lived is definitely wrong. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure about it. Sorry for using it in this site! :(

Comment: Look at this: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_was_the_time_period_called_when_Shakespeare_lived in answer two, one row before last one you find this sentences: "William Shakespeare lived from 1564-1616, meaning all but the last 13 years of his life were lived during the Elizabethan period of English history" Is it incorrect in order to using "were lived" ?

Comment: @user37324 Ah, okay, let me rephrase: "were lived" is incorrect in the sentence you were using it in. It isn't incorrect *all* the time.  I think it would be a great idea to post another question, with both sentences, and have someone answer with the rules there. That way you can get your second question answered and others can easily find the answer in search :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Thanks! I found why it is correct in the link. It refers to " the last 13..." not to the Shakespeare.